# Angular Material Grid Layout

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material2

What are predefined classes for grid layout in Angular Material? We have `"row","col-sm-4"` etc.. classes in bootstrap. Do we have these type of classes in Angular Material 2?
Thanks.

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/overview

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll give you the basics.

In Angular Material (for Angular 2/4) the most commonly used attributes are:

```
fxLayout="row | column"
fxLayoutAlign="start | center | end | stretch | space-around | space-between | none" (can accept 2 properties at the same time)
fxFlex="number" (can accept numbers from 1 to 100)
```

You can also use postfix as `fxLayout.xs` and so on to apply rules only for specific resolution.

For more info you can look through the docs: https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/API-Documentation

To play around with alignment, you can use the demonstration from Angularjs Material resource (it's totally the same as for Angular Material for Angular 2/4): https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/alignment

[image]

And another one useful link: https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs

Comment: Thank you..can I use angular js layout in angular2??

Comment: @hari, can't say really, I didn't try to do that. They are totally the same, just some differences in syntax: for example you use `layout-align="center"` in Angular Material 1, and the equivalent in Angular Material 2 will be `fxLayoutAlign="center"`. I recommend that you do not reinvent the wheel, just use new syntax, it's pretty easy and they are very similar

Comment: Ok..Got it..Thank you so much.. @Commercial Suicide

Comment: @hari, Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample example that should help you understand more how to use the grid by looking at the code for this example. I suggest you try it out and play with the cols numbers, and colspans and rowspans to understand what each of them do. I hope this was helpful!

```
<mat-grid-list cols = "5" rowHeight = "25vh">
    <mat-grid-tile 
    [colspan] = "1"
    [rowspan] = "1">1
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile 
    [colspan] = "3"
    [rowspan] = "1">2
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile 
    [colspan] = "1"
    [rowspan] = "1">3
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile 
    [colspan] = "1"
    [rowspan] = "1">11
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile 
    [colspan] = "3"
    [rowspan] = "1">22
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile 
    [colspan] = "1"
    [rowspan] = "1">33
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile 
    [colspan] = "1"
    [rowspan] = "1">111
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile 
    [colspan] = "3"
    [rowspan] = "1">222
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile 
    [colspan] = "1"
    [rowspan] = "1">333
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile 
    [colspan] = "5"
    [rowspan] = 1> 4444
    </mat-grid-tile>
 </mat-grid-list>
```